# IN LWC lightning-tree-grid I want to Remove Wrap Text/Clip Text Options from header

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I need some help in removing Wrap Text/Clip Text options for tree grid.

Comment: You can post your code snippet here on what you have done. It will help the community to view what you have done and they can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Add `hideDefaultActions:true` attribute to the column definition to suppress the default action menu. The documentation doesn't make this immediately clear, as it refers you to the [lightning-tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) to find this option.

Comment: I added the attribute  hideDefaultActions:true  to the column definition, but its  not working in the lighting tree grid .